# IE8 doesn't work

Tags: sharepoint-server, ajax, ie

I'm using Ajax call for API in Sharepoint 2010. I don't have that much Access to edit master page.

I also use the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> 
<html xmlns:mso="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" 
xmlns:msdt="uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882">   
 <head>  
    <!--<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge"/>-->
     <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
    <!--<title>WiFi Home</title>-->
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"/>   
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" 
 href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/smoothness/jquer
y-ui.css"/>

<script type="text/javascript" 
src="https://..../SiteAssets/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>      
   <script type="text/javascript" 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/jquery-ui.min.js">
</script>
       <!--<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
 href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.12/css/dataTables.jqueryui.min.css">  -->  
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js">
</script>  

<script type="text/javascript" 
src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/gasparesganga-jquery-loading-
overlay@1.5.4/src/loadingoverlay.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/gasparesganga-jquery-loading-
overlay@1.5.4/extras/loadingoverlay_progress/loadingoverlay_progress.min.js">
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Inserting `<!DOCTYPE html>` in the masterpage/publishing page forces HTML5 to be rendered -- which IE8 does not support.

Comment: You mean take out <!DOCTYPE html> from My code? Or from master page? Thanks a lot

Comment: And how do I fix?

Comment: If you tried to insert that 2nd doctype in there -- i'd suggest removing it.

Comment: I did remove in my code, but still facing

Comment: You are using jquery 3.x, you should be using jquery 1.x with SharePoint 2010

Comment: Error: No transport

Comment: you are again making a cross domain call---stop that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73796/discussion-between-sai-and-mike).